# How to freeze ruby standard library?

Tags: ruby, security

Ruby allows to re-open any class and re-implement or override methods.

Gems under supply chain attack can re-open standard library classes or core classes, re-implement frequently used methods and start recording or logging important data (say Net:HTTP library's GET/POST calls).

How do we `freeze` standard library classes such that the process crashes or throws warning when a rogue gem tries to re-open/re-implement them?

ActiveSupport is a popular library that does quite a lot of this. Outside ActiveSupport and gems that are too popular where its hard to not detect a supply chain attack, other gems need to cross some sort of fencing before they are allowed to override ruby std library or std/core classes.

Does ruby (or) rails community address this concern in any way today?

Comment: _"How to freeze ruby standard library?"_ – you can call `freeze` on a class to prevent modification. But this won't make your application supply chain attack proof. A gem can run arbitrary code within your application – even at the C level. I doubt that you can safely run a malicious gem. In fact, merely installing it might be enough to patch your Ruby lib.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan. Was aware of calling `freeze` on a class.